# Catching exceptions with BeginRead in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, asynchronous

When using asynchronous code to read from streams etc using the BeginXXX / EndXXX pattern, I believe that any exceptions that occur during the process will be thrown when the call to EndXXX is made.

Does this mean that the initial call to BeginXXX will never throw an exception, it will always be thrown by EndXXX?

Or to put it another way, **should I enclose BeginRead with try{}catch{} as well?**

```
public StartReading()
{
        // Should this be enclosed with try{}catch{} ?
        stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(readCallback), stream);
}

private void readCallback(IAsyncResult result)
{
    Stream stream = (Stream)result.AsyncState;

    try
    {
        int len = stream.EndRead(result);

        // Do work...

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Error handling stuff.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, **any** code can throw an exception, so "never" is strong... for example, `OutOfMemoryException`, `ThreadAbortException`, or some other exception that indicates resource saturation (for example, it somehow can't start the async operation).

It *might* (although I haven't tested) also throw *immediately* if that is a write-only stream. And it will *certainly* throw immediately if `stream` turns out to be `null`.

However! In all the cases I've mentioned, the correct behaviour is probably to let it bubble up; they all indicate pretty fundamental problems unrelated to the current logic. So no: I wouldn't `try`/`catch` here unless there was something **specific** I expected and wanted to handle somehow.

Comment: I figured that 'never' would generate an opinion :)  The code posted was just a skeleton to explain my question, so, assuming I do proper checks on the parameters passed to BeginXXX, any exceptions will not be specific to the call itself, but rather for the application as a whole?

Comment: @Andy - exceptions relating to *reading the data* should come out from `EndXXX`. "Braindead exceptions" (see Eric Lippert's blog) or sickly-process exceptions can come from anywhere.

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the 'Braindead exceptions' reference alone!

Answer (score 1):

A simple proof:

```
public StartReading()
{      
    // Should this be enclosed with try{}catch{} ?
    buffer = null; // now it will throw
    stream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(readCallback), stream);
}
```

So Yes, you should anticipate on exceptions here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my comment to Marc.

Comment: @Andy Yes, I agree that most cases would be irrelevant. The one thing to worry about here is the Stream. If it is not-null but somehow invalid, will the exception happen in BeginRead or in EndRead ? (I don't know).